# All Actions tab broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page

Accessing the "All actions" tab on the profile page on the main site now reliably results in a Oops! Something Bad Happened! page.

The error page appears after a roughly 30 seconds delay.

URL to test with: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=all

As noted in the comments, [only the <kbd>All</kbd> subtab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398964/all-actions-tab-broken#comment779724_398964) appears to have this problem, and [only if there are enough actions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398964/all-actions-tab-broken#comment779730_398964) to begin with.

Works fine on meta.

Comment: You have reached your maximum action limit, please come back in 6 to 8 weeks ;)

Comment: Can confirm that the All tab doesn't load for me either. Other subtabs do work. I'm on Chrome/ Win10 and in Western Europe but I doubt that is the root cause.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 77. It's possible it's related to the profiles themselves. EDIT: my bad - I can reproduce it. I was just on the Comments tab, rather than the All tab.

Comment: Quick check: does https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=badges load for you?

Comment: @rene All the subtabs do, except `All`.

Comment: Same here. It's always been slow for me, maybe now it hits a SQL timeout somewhere?

Comment: @CodeCaster yeah, probably a rogue query.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Chrome/Win10, Western Europe. The page loads in less than a second with the normal speed. Edit: I can reproduce on other users. My own page loads fast, but the action page of other users loads very slow.

Comment: It works for me on All actions->all (Firefox 77). I'm sad, it probably means I haven't performed enough actions

Comment: Appears to have started to work as of now.

Comment: Seems to work now, yes. It's loading slower than normal it still loads.

Comment: Don't see any problems with it now... Likely some temporary issue... We probably should start new one if it happens again.