# All Actions tab broken again

Tags: bug, profile-page

Accessing the "All actions" tab on the profile page on the main site now reliably results in a Oops! Something Bad Happened! page.

The error page appears after a roughly 30 seconds delay.

URLs to test with:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=all
  Your activity. The result should depend on how much you have there.
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=activity
  An [active user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400506/11683)'s activity. Should fail every time.

This [happened before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398964/11683) and was quickly fixed (but tagged no-repro like it happens for some reason with problems that are quickly fixed).

Like before, it may only be happening to users with a lot of history.

Now it happens again; starting a new question about it [as suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398964/all-actions-tab-broken#comment779820_398964).

---

<s>As of 2020-09-09 01:00pm UTC: my 'All actions' gives a one second delay, Gordon Linoff's gives a 5 seconds delay; no Oops.</s>

---

<s>As of 2021-04-27 07:47am UTC: Started happening again. This time though, the Gordon Linoff's link works fine every time, whereas mine (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg?tab=activity&sort=all) fails every time after 30 seconds.</s>
Works again.

---

<s>As of 2021-06-22 09:56am UTC: Started happening again. This time, again, the Gordon Linoff's link works fine every time, whereas mine (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg?tab=activity&sort=all) fails every time after 30 seconds. Another user [posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408548/11683) a question about it.</s>
Works again as of 2021-06-22 10:35am UTC.

---

<s>As of 2021-10-29 08:02am UTC: Started happening again. This time, *again*, the Gordon Linoff's link works fine every time, whereas mine (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11683/gserg?tab=activity&sort=all) fails every time after 30 seconds. Another user [posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412663/11683) a question about it.</s>
Works again as of 2021-10-29 09:15am UTC.

Comment: Yeah, that is taking too long for me as well. We're too active! Stop doing that!

Comment: I can only mention that the problem doesn't seem to occur when you don't have a long history! Or the problem was solved.

Comment: @Damien Still happens for me. Try https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=activity

Comment: Effectively, I got the same problem as yours when using the last link you provide in the comment. It confirms it is not an internet acces problem or a navigator problem.

Comment: It works for me. No "Oops! Something Bad Happened!"

Comment: I believe 5 seconds is exactly the time that a call is allowed to run. Once that 5 seconds are over you either have a response, an Oops or an Maintenance page.

Comment: I've noticed SO being a bit slow compared to usual to serve pages in general the past few days. I just assume there'll be some statistic they'll see and make appropriate adjustments, seeing as low latency is something they aim for.