# Activity tab broken again

Tags: bug, activity-tab

Clicking the "All Actions" tab in my profile takes me to an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error page:

[image: error page]

This issue seems to have [happened many times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=activity%20tab%20oops) in the past.

Comment: It is timing out for me as well when I visit your activities. My own all activities has a similar problem. If you only have [105 actions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15459094/denis-turgenev?tab=activity) then the page loads fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, I can't repro with mine but can with both of yours

Comment: I can go to "All actions" on your main account, but it completely ignores me pressing on "All". The other tabs work fine. Not sure what's up with rene's because that just goes directly into that screen you posted. I guess Stack just broke rene :(

Comment: Fixed again, till next time.

Comment: This seems to be working for me now. @rene, can you confirm that it works on your profile now? Or is this a geographic issue?

Comment: @CodyGray not blasting fast as other pages so SQL Server seems to be struggling but it does load for me now, yes.